# Continuity Set of Monotone Functions

Tags: analysis, self-learning

Let $f$ be a real-valued monotone function defined on an interval $I$. Then we know that the set $D \subset I$ of discontinuities of the first kind is at most countable. ***Then can I say that the complement $C=I\backslash D$ of $D$ is dense, please?***

I suppose this is true since we can imagine getting rid of all rationals (may be bigger than $D$) in $I$ and still end up with a dense set. ***If so, can I claim that the complement of a countable set in an uncountable set is dense, please? Thank you!***

Comment: complement of a countable D set is dense in I since consider any neighbourhood of a any point,that nbd has uncounably many point where D has only countably many point so you can get a sequence from complement of D which converge to that point but in general any uncountable set need not be dense as for example Cantor set ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the complement is not dense, then there is an open set $(a,b)\subseteq I$ such that $I\setminus D\cap (a,b)=\varnothing$ But since we have a bijection of $(a,b)$ with $(0,1)$--namely $f(x) = {1\over b-a}(x-a)$--which is known to be uncountable by Cantor's diagonalization argument to be uncountable, it is impossible that $(a,b)\subseteq D$, hence no open subset of $I$ lacks points of $I\setminus D$, and so it is dense.